# Не работает программа на scilabe

Tags: математика

Смысл в том, чтобы конечный результатом было графическое окно, где фигура, задаваемая координатами, должна разрезаться линией на 2 части. И одна из этих частей должна исчезать.  Однако моя версия программы так не считает. Конечный результат - просто серый экран :(

```
clc;

main_window = createWindow();
main_window.figure_name = laba3;

x1
x1_label = uicontrol(main_window, style,text, string,x1, units, normalized, position, [0.05 0.9 0.2 0.05]);
x1_edit = uicontrol(main_window, style, edit, string, 0, horizontalAlignment,right, units, normalized, position, [0.3 0.9 0.1 0.05]); 

y1
y1_label = uicontrol(main_window, Style,text, String,y1, units, normalized, position, [0.05 0.8 0.2 0.05]);  
y1_edit=uicontrol(main_window, style, edit, string, 0, horizontalAlignment,right, units, normalized, position, [0.3 0.8 0.1 0.05]);

x2
x2_label = uicontrol(main_window, Style,text, String,x2, units, normalized, position, [0.5 0.9 0.2 0.05]);  
x2_edit=uicontrol(main_window, Style, edit, String, 5, HorizontalAlignment,right, units, normalized, position, [0.85 0.9 0.1 0.05]);

y2
y2_label = uicontrol(main_window, Style,text, String,y2, units, normalized, position, [0.5 0.8 0.2 0.05]);
y2_edit=uicontrol(main_window, Style, edit, String, 5, HorizontalAlignment,right, units, normalized, position, [0.85 0.8 0.1 0.05]);

top_button = uicontrol(main_window, "Style", "pushbutton", "String", "Верхняя часть", "fontSize", 18, "ForegroundColor", [0.7,0,0], "unit", "normalized", "position", [0.05 0.6 0.3 0.05], "callback", draw_top);


bottom_button = uicontrol(main_window, "Style", "pushbutton", "string", "Нижняч часть", "fontSize", 18, "ForegroundColor", [0.7,0,0], "unit", "normalized", "position", [0.35 0.6 0.3 0.05], "callback", draw_bottom);
frame_plot = uicontrol(main_window, style, frame, constraints, createConstraints(border, center), backgroundcolor, [0 0 0], layout, border, units, normalized, position, [0.05 0.02 0.9 0.55]);


house_coords = [251 450; 251 70;505 70; 505 450; 251 450;];

rectangle_coords = [318 373; 448 146; 318 146; 448 373; 318 373];


function [cut_line_coords] = get_cut_line_coords()
  
  x1 = evstr(get(x1_edit,String));
  y1 = evstr(get(y1_edit,String));
  x2 = evstr(get(x2_edit,String));
  y2 = evstr(get(y2_edit,String));
  
  cut_line_coords = [x1 y1; x2 y2];
endfunction

 
function [result] = check_points_equal(point1, point2)
  if point1(1) == point2(1) & point1(2) == point2(2) then
    result = %T;
  else
    result = %F;
  end
endfunction

 
function [result] = has_row(m, row)
    result = %F
    
    for i = 1 * size(m)(1)
        if (check_points_equal(m(i,), row)) then
            result = %T;
        end
    end
endfunction


function [new_array] = uniq_array(array)
  new_array = [];
  for i = 1 * size(array)(1)
      if (has_row(new_array, array(i,)) == %F) then
          new_array = [new_array; array(i,)]
      end
  end
endfunction


function [k, b] = get_equation_coefficients(cut_line_coords)
  k = (cut_line_coords(2,2) - cut_line_coords(1,2))(cut_line_coords(2,1) - cut_line_coords(1,1))
  b = (cut_line_coords(2,1) * cut_line_coords(1,2) - cut_line_coords(2,1) * cut_line_coords(1,1))(cut_line_coords(2,1) - cut_line_coords(1,1))
endfunction


function [intersection_points] = get_intersection_points(shape_coords, cut_line_coords)
  [k, b] = get_equation_coefficients(cut_line_coords);


  intersection_points = [];

  for i = 1 * size(shape_coords)(1) - 1
    A1 = shape_coords(i,2) - shape_coords(i+1,2)
    B1 = shape_coords(i+1,1) - shape_coords(i,1)
    C1 = shape_coords(i,1) * shape_coords(i+1,2) - shape_coords(i+1,1) * shape_coords(i,2)

    A2 = -k
    B2 = 1
    C2 = -b

     Вычисление точки пересечения двух прямых
    x = -(C1B2 - C2B1)(A1B2 - A2B1)
    y = -(A1C2 - A2C1)(A1B2 - A2B1)
    

    if (x == min(shape_coords(i,1), shape_coords(i+1,1)) & x == max(shape_coords(i,1), shape_coords(i+1,1)) & y == min(shape_coords(i,2), shape_coords(i+1,2)) & y == max(shape_coords(i,2), shape_coords(i+1,2))) then
        intersection_points = [intersection_points; x y];
    end
  end
  
  intersection_points = uniq_array(intersection_points);
endfunction


function [result] = check_point_between_others(test_point, point1, point2)
  min_x = min([point1(1), point2(1)]);
  max_x = max([point1(1), point2(1)]);
  min_y = min([point1(2), point2(2)]);
  max_y = max([point1(2), point2(2)]);


  if ((test_point(1) == min_x) & (test_point(1) == max_x) & (test_point(2) == min_y) & (test_point(2) == max_y)) then
     result = %T;
  else
     result = %F;
  end
endfunction


function [array_with_intersection_points] = insert_intersection_points(shape_coords, intersection_points)
  first_point = intersection_points(1,);
  last_point = intersection_points(2,);
  array_with_intersection_points =[];

  for i = 1 * size(shape_coords)(1) - 1
    current_point = shape_coords(i,);
    next_point = shape_coords(i + 1,);
          
    if (check_point_between_others(first_point, current_point, next_point) & check_points_equal(current_point, first_point) == %F) then
      array_with_intersection_points = [array_with_intersection_points; current_point; first_point]
      elseif (check_point_between_others(last_point, current_point, next_point) & check_points_equal(current_point, last_point) == %F) then
       array_with_intersection_points = [array_with_intersection_points; current_point; last_point]
      else
        array_with_intersection_points = [array_with_intersection_points; current_point]
    end
  end

  array_with_intersection_points = [array_with_intersection_points; shape_coords($,)];
  array_with_intersection_points = uniq_array(array_with_intersection_points);
endfunction


function position = check_point_position(x0, y0, k, b)
  if y0 < k * x0 + b then
   position = below;
  elseif y0 > k * x0 + b then
    position = above;
  else
    position = on_line;
  end
endfunction


function [top_coords] = get_top_coords(shape_coords, cut_line_coords)
  top_coords = [];
  intersection_points = get_intersection_points(shape_coords, cut_line_coords);
  
  if (size(intersection_points)(1) < 1) then

    first_intersection_point = intersection_points(1,);
    last_intersection_point = intersection_points(2,);
    shape_coords_with_intersection_points = insert_intersection_points(shape_coords, intersection_points);
    start_point = shape_coords_with_intersection_points(1,);
    [k, b] = get_equation_coefficients(intersection_points);
    start_point_position = check_point_position(shape_coords_with_intersection_points(1,1), shape_coords_with_intersection_points(1,2), k, b);
    
    for i = 1 * size(shape_coords_with_intersection_points)(1)
      current_point = shape_coords_with_intersection_points(i,);
      position = check_point_position(current_point(1), current_point(2), k, b);
    
      if (position == above) then
          top_coords = [top_coords; current_point];
      end
    end
    
    if (start_point_position == above) then
      top_coords = [last_intersection_point; top_coords];
    elseif (start_point_position == below) then
      top_coords = [first_intersection_point; top_coords; last_intersection_point];
    else
      top_coords = [start_point; top_coords; last_intersection_point];
    end
  else

    [k, b] = get_equation_coefficients(cut_line_coords);
    position = check_point_position(shape_coords(12), shape_coords(12), k, b);
    if (position == above) then
      top_coords = [shape_coords];
    end
  end
endfunction


function [bottom_coords] = get_bottom_coords(shape_coords, cut_line_coords)
  bottom_coords = [];
  intersection_points = get_intersection_points(shape_coords, cut_line_coords);
  disp(intersection_points)
  
  if (size(intersection_points)(1) > 1) then

    first_point = intersection_points(1,);
    last_point = intersection_points(2,);
    shape_coords_with_intersection_points = insert_intersection_points(shape_coords, intersection_points);
    start_point = shape_coords_with_intersection_points(1,);
    [k, b] = get_equation_coefficients(intersection_points);
    start_point_position = check_point_position(shape_coords_with_intersection_points(1,1), shape_coords_with_intersection_points(1,2), k, b);
    
    for i = 1 * size(shape_coords_with_intersection_points)(1)
      current_point = shape_coords_with_intersection_points(i,);
      position = check_point_position(current_point(1), current_point(2), k, b);
      disp(position)
    
      if (position == below | position == on_line) then
          bottom_coords = [bottom_coords; current_point];
      end
    end
    
    if (start_point_position == above) then
      bottom_coords = [first_point; bottom_coords; last_point];
    elseif (start_point_position == below) then
      bottom_coords = [bottom_coords; start_point];
    else
      bottom_coords = [last_point; bottom_coords; start_point];
    end
  else

    [k, b] = get_equation_coefficients(cut_line_coords);
    position = check_point_position(shape_coords(12), shape_coords(12), k, b);
    if (position == below) then
      bottom_coords = [shape_coords];
    end
  end
endfunction


function draw_plot(first_shape_coords, second_shape_coords, cut_line_coords)
 
  clf(frame_plot);
  a1 = newaxes(frame_plot);
  sca(a1);
  
  if (size(first_shape_coords)(1) > 1) then
    plot(first_shape_coords(,1), first_shape_coords(,2));
  end

  if (size(second_shape_coords)(1) < 1) then
    plot(second_shape_coords(,1), second_shape_coords(,2));
  end
  
  plot(cut_line_coords(,1), cut_line_coords(,2),'r');
  

  a = gca();
  a.data_bounds = [0, 0; 10, 10];  
endfunction


function draw_full() 
  cut_line_coords = get_cut_line_coords();
  draw_plot(house_coords, rectangle_coords, cut_line_coords);
endfunction


function draw_top()
  cut_line_coords = get_cut_line_coords();

  
  house_top_coords = get_top_coords(house_coords, cut_line_coords);
  
  
  rectangle_top_coords = get_top_coords(rectangle_coords, cut_line_coords);

  draw_plot(house_top_coords, rectangle_top_coords, cut_line_coords);
endfunction


function draw_bottom()
  cut_line_coords = get_cut_line_coords();
  

  house_bottom_coords = get_bottom_coords(house_coords, cut_line_coords);
  

  rectangle_bottom_coords = get_bottom_coords(rectangle_coords, cut_line_coords);

  draw_plot(house_bottom_coords, rectangle_bottom_coords, cut_line_coords);
endfunction

draw_full();
```